# Conditionally pipe streams in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

I want to conditionally pipe streams in a nice way. The behaviour I want to achieve is the following:

```
if (someBoolean) {

  stream = fs
    .createReadStream(filepath)
    .pipe(decodeStream(someOptions))
    .pipe(writeStream);

} else {

  stream = fs
    .createReadStream(filepath)
    .pipe(writeStream);

}
```

So I prepared all my streams, and if `someBoolean` is true, I want to add an additional stream to the pipe.

Then I thought I found a solution with [detour-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detour-stream), but unfortunately didn't manage to set this up. I used notation similar to [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if), because this was mentioned as inspiration:

```
var detour = require('detour-stream');

stream = fs
  .createReadStream(filepath)
  .detour(someBoolean, decodeStream(someOptions))
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

But this unfortunately only results in an error:

```
  .detour(someBoolean, decodeStream(someOptions))
 ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`detour` is a function that creates a writable stream: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

Thus, from your example, this should work:

```
var detour = require('detour-stream');

stream = fs
  .createReadStream(filepath)
  .pipe(detour(someBoolean, decodeStream(someOptions))) // just pipe it
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

x-posted from https://github.com/dashed/detour-stream/issues/2#issuecomment-231423878

Comment: This is blatantly obvious. :-) I didn't think of that, thanks!

Comment: doesn't seem to work now, my stream ends prematurely whenever detour is used, works fine when I hard code it